# How to score yahtzee in c++

Tags: c++

I am writing a yahtzee game for my c++ programming class.  One of my difficulties I have ran into is the scoring system for different categories.  I think I have figured out how to do it for adding 1s, 2s etc but I do not know how to have the program determine when a 3 of a kind, 4 of a kind, etc has been rolled.  Here is my code so far.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //Declare variables
    int players;
    int turn = 1;
    vector<string> names;
    string playerName;
    int dice[5];
    int finalScore = 0;
    char reroll[5];
    char rollDice;
    int tries = 1;
    const int DICE = 5;
    int roll[DICE];
    int scorecard;
    int scoreThisTurn(int scorecard);
    int turnScore = 0;

    //Introduction, get number of players.
    cout << "Hello, welcome to Yahtzee!  How many players are there?" << endl;
    cin >> players;

    if (players > 4) {
        cout << "Sorry, the maximum number of players is 4." << endl;
        cout << "How many players are there?" << endl;
        cin >> players;
    }

    //Get player names
    string getNames();
    for (int i = 0; i < players; i++)  {
        cout << "Hello player " << i + 1 << ", please enter your name" << endl;
        cin >> playerName;
            names.push_back(playerName);
        }

    srand(time(NULL));  //random seed

    cout << "Welcome to Yahtzee!\n";

    while (turn <= 13) {       //roll dice
        cout << "Press 'r' to roll" << endl;
        cin >> rollDice;
        if (rollDice == 'r') {
            for (int i = 0; i < DICE; i++) {
                roll[i] = rand() % 6 + 1;
            }
        }
        cout << "You rolled: " << roll[0] << ", " << roll[1] << ", " <<
            roll[2] << ", " << roll[3] << ", " << roll[4] << endl;
        cout << "Type y to reroll or n to keep.  For example yynnn would keep the first three dice" << endl;
        cin >> reroll[0] >> reroll[1] >> reroll[2] >> reroll[3] >> reroll[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < DICE; i++) {
            if (reroll[i] == 'y') {
                roll[i] = rand() % 6 + 1;
            }
            else if (reroll[i] == 'n') {
                roll[i];
            }
            else cout << "Sorry you entered an invalid letter." << endl;
        }

        cout << "Your second roll is: " << roll[0] << ", " << roll[1] << ", " <<
            roll[2] << ", " << roll[3] << ", " << roll[4] << endl;

        cout << "Type y to reroll or n to keep.  For example yynnn would keep the first three dice" << endl;
        cin >> reroll[0] >> reroll[1] >> reroll[2] >> reroll[3] >> reroll[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < DICE; i++) {
            if (reroll[i] == 'y') {
                roll[i] = rand() % 6 + 1;
            }
            else if (reroll[i] == 'n') {
                roll[i];
            }
            else cout << "Sorry you entered an invalid letter." << endl;
        }

        cout << "Your third roll is: " << roll[0] << ", " << roll[1] << ", " <<
            roll[2] << ", " << roll[3] << ", " << roll[4] << endl;

        //displays scorecard categories
        cout << "Which category would you like to score this in" << endl;
        cout << "1 - ones: " << endl;
        cout << "2 - twos: " << endl;
        cout << "3 - threes: " << endl;
        cout << "4 - fours: " << endl;
        cout << "5 - fives: " << endl;
        cout << "6 - sixes: " << endl;
        cout << "7 - 3 of a kind: " << endl;
        cout << "8 - 4 of a kind: " << endl;
        cout << "9 - small straight: " << endl;
        cout << "10 - large straight: " << endl;
        cout << "11 - full house: " << endl;
        cout << "12 - yahtzee: " << endl;
        cout << "13 - chance: " << endl;

        //asks player to choose where to score
        cout << "\nEnter 1-14 to choose a category." << endl;
        cin >> scorecard;

        //assigns points
        for (int i = 0; i < DICE; i++) {
            turnScore = 0;
            if (scorecard == 1) {
                if (roll[i] == 1) {
                    turnScore = turnScore + 1;
                }
            }
            if (scorecard == 2) {
                if (roll[i] == 2) {
                    turnScore = turnScore + 2;
                }
            }
            if (scorecard == 3) {
                if (roll[i] == 3) {
                    turnScore = turnScore + 3;
                }
            }
            if (scorecard == 4) {
                if (roll[i] == 4) {
                    turnScore = turnScore + 4;
                }
            }
            if (scorecard == 5) {
                if (roll[i] == 5) {
                    turnScore = turnScore + 5;
                }
            }
            if (scorecard == 6) {
                if (roll[i] == 6) {
                    turnScore = turnScore + 6;
                }
                if (scorecard == 7) {
                    if (roll[i] == 2) {
                        turnScore = turnScore + 2;
                    }
                }

        }

        cout << scorecard << endl;

        turn++;
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I've set up the scoring for the first 6 categories but don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Comment: @qix 2 problems currently.  When I try to score 1's for example the dice read 11211, the score should = 4, however the output is 1.  I have since moved the initialization of turnScore to 0 outside of the initial scoring loop but the problem remains.  The second problem is I do not know how to go about scoring a 3 of a kind, 4 of a kind etc.  How can I get the program to recognize one of these types of rolls and score it accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

> I do not know how to have the program determine when a 3 of a kind, 4 of a kind, etc has been rolled.

1. Create a variable to help you keep track of the number of dice that have a given number.

   ```
   int diceCount[DICE] = {0};
   ```

   and fill up the array with:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < DICE; i++) {
      diceCount[roll[i-1]]++
   }
   ```
2. Create helper functions to determine whether five, four, or three of a kind have been thrown.

   ```
   int getNOfAKind(int diceCount[], int N)
   {
      // This will need moving DICE out of `main`
      // making it a global variable.
      for ( int i = 0; i < DICE; ++i )
      {
         if (diceCount[i] == N )
         {
            return i+1;
         }
      }
      return -1;
   }

   int getFiveOfAKind(int diceCount[])
   {
      return getNOfAKind(diceCount, 5);
   }

   int getFourOfAKind(int diceCount[])
   {
      return getNOfAKind(diceCount, 4);
   }

   int getThreeOfAKind(int diceCount[])
   {
      return getNOfAKind(diceCount, 3);
   }
   ```

   and use it as:

   ```
   int fiveCount = getFiveOfAKind(diceCount);
   if ( fiveCount != -1 )
   {
   }

   int fourCount = getFourOfAKind(diceCount);
   if ( fourCount != -1 )
   {
   }

   int threeCount = getThreeOfAKind(diceCount);
   if ( threeCount != -1 )
   {
   }
   ```

Comment: @R Sahu Thank you for your reply.  I will try this.  Looking at my code, do you know why when scoring for 1s, 2s, etc the output is incorrect?  For example if the dice read 22111, the output for 2s should be 4 but it comes out as 2.  I have moved the statement initializing turnScore to 0 outside the initial loop but the problem persists.

Comment: @RyanA, You need to move the line `turnScore = 0;` outside the `for` loop. Otherwise, it gets initialized to `0` on every iteration of the loop.